# How to bind data when user clicks on a particular card it displays on a popup card?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

when user clicks on any card which contains the data (the data is getting from backend api GET method)that data should bind-up or displays on a pop-card ,How to do this thing .in my case i have two components one is DisplayNotes.vue and another one is UpdateNotes.vue .when ever user clicks on any displayed cards that data is bind to the updateNotes card(popup) .How to pass that data to the pop-up card ,please help me to fix this issue.

[DisplayNotes.vue]

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section" >
    <div  v-for="note in notes" :key="note.data"  id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle()" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
import UpdateNotes from './UpdateNotes.vue'
export default {
    name: 'DisplayNotes',
    components: {
        icons,UpdateNotes
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited notes..'
            }, ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayNotes().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        toggle(){
            var blur=document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active');

            var popup=document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');
        }
      
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.carddisplay-section{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-around;
    gap: 10px;
}
.container {
    height: 180px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #e0dede;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-right: -15%;
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
}
.card-content {
    h5 {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 18px;
        width: 90%;
        height: 60px;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        padding: 7.5px 10px;
        outline: none;
    }
}
.card-button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 240px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
.note-icons {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.note {
    &:hover {
        .note-icons {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
}
.imported-icons {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
#blur.active{
    filter:blur(0.5px);
    // pointer-events: none;
    // user-select: none;
}
#popup{
    position: fixed;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#popup.active{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.card-content p,h5 { 
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
```

This is my updateNotes.vue(popup card)
[UpdateNotes.vue]

```
<template>
 <div  class="update" >
        <form class="update-note" @submit.prevent="handlesubmit" autocomplete="off">
            <input name="title"  v-model="title" placeholder="Title" />
            <textarea name="content" v-model="body" style="resize: none" placeholder="Take a note..." rows="3"></textarea>
            <div class="btm-icons">
                <icons />
                <button id="btn-section"  type="submit" >Close</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import icons from './icons.vue'
export default{
    components:{icons},
    methods:{
      flip() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
    }
}

</script>
<style scoped>
.update {
  padding-top: 0%;
  
}

.update-note {
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 152px auto;
  margin-right: 80%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #ccc;
}
.update-note input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 4px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply bind the data to want to send to the child component as a prop. In your case you put in on the component like this:

`<UpdateNotes :body="note.body"></UpdateNotes>`

Then, you would have to define the prop in the other component unless you want to get it from `$refs`:

```js
<script>

export default{
    props: {
        body: String
    }
}

</script>
```

Note that it is not recommended to alter props, so you might want to duplicate the `body` prop in your `data()` section. Then, you could bind that new (now local) data property to the textarea. In the `beforeDestroy` hook of your component, you then can call a method that compares the local property to the prop and use `this.$emit` to inform the parent component of any changes.

Comment: Hello @cmc, Here my parent component is DisplayNotes.vue and child is UpdateNote.vue, where to add this script and  when i am adding <UpdateNotes :body="note.body"></UpdateNotes> the card is not visible, How to use $emit..?

Comment: To make it visible depending on button state, you could add a v-if property to the child component. As I don't know what your `toggle()` function does since it calls an external function, I cannot tell you how to access the button state. As for `$emit`: you call `this.$emit('someString', data)` on the child and catch the data with `@emit="doSomething"`.

Comment: To clarify since I cannot edit my comment above: with `this.$emit`, you emit an event to the parent. This event can be caught with the `v-on` handle vue provides. I misrepresented the syntax in the comment above. Correct use would be: in child `this.$emit('someEvent', data)`, in parent `<ChildComponent :prop="someData" v-on:someEvent="doSomething(data)"></ChildComponent>`. Note that the part after v-on is the string you first emitted. You can also use the short syntax `@someEvent="..."`

Comment: Thank You @cmc,toggle() function here i am using for background blur when user clicked on any card

Comment: I think the problem is that you only bind a css class with `toggle()`. You would have to toggle a boolean that is bound to your child component to make it show on toggle.